# How to add events to dynamically created added HTML with vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, dom

My code add HTML snippet to body dynamically. then all actions need to do to added html. this can do with jquery. is there equivalent vanilla javascript method to do this without jquery?

```
    <body>
    <script>
// create elem1 dynamically.
     document.querySelector('body').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<div id="elm1"></div>');
//do action to elem1 with jquery
    $("#elm1").html('<div></div>'); 
    $("#elm1").on('click',function(){
  alert("hi");   
  }); 
 //how can I do above jquery actions with vanilla js? Is it possible?
    </script>
    </body>
```

I tried

```
document.getElementById('elm1').innerHTML('<div></div>')
```

not working.

Answer (score 1):

[.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) is not used like that.

1. [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) is native JS.
2. ('#elm1') can be replaced by [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

```
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<div id="elm1"></div>');
//do action to elem1 with jquery
    document.getElementById('elm1').innerHTML = '<div></div>'; 
    document.getElementById('elm1').onclick = function(){
  alert("hi");   
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let elm1 = document.querySelector("#elm1");
elm1.innerHTML = '<div></div>';
elm1.addEventListener("click", () => alert('hi'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why. but innerHTML didn't work.
It solved by adding insertAdjacentHTML instead innerHTML

```
document.querySelector('body').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<div id="elm1"></div>')
document.getElementById('elm1').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<div></div>')
```